# Python Requests - IP address and User Agent rotators still getting captcha how to bypass

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am using the below 2 libraries to rotate my user agent and IP address, while web scraping
but still, somehow I am getting captcha.

```
from random_user_agent.user_agent import UserAgent
from requests_ip_rotator import ApiGateway
```

Any suggestion please what may be triggering the captcha?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>ShieldSquare Captcha</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="notranslate" name="google">
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.SSJSInternal = 5449;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the site has 24/7 captcha , and the appearance of captcha doesnt depend on the user agent or ip address

Or the website is using other payload/header fields which determines wether to give a captcha or not

Hope this helps :)